# Customizing collator rules doesn't work

Tags: java, collections, collation

I have a string rule like:

```
String MACEDONIAN_ALPH = "А < Б < В < Г < Д < Ѓ < Е < Ж < З < S < И < Ј < К < Л < Љ < М < Н < Њ < О < П < Р < С < Т < Ќ < У < Ф < Х < Ц < Ч < Џ < Ш";
```

Then I create the `RuleBasedCollator`:

```
try {
    macedonian_collator = new RuleBasedCollator(MACEDONIAN_ALPH);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And when I call `Collections.sort(arrayList, macedonian_collator);` it doesn't sort from the predefined rules.
It sorts `arrayList` ascending from `Ѓ, Ј` etc., after that it sorts good

EDIT: here is added the minimal example

```
ArrayList<String> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    citiesList.add("ЈАНЕ САНДАНСКИ");
    citiesList.add("СКОПЈЕ");
    citiesList.add("БЕЛГРАД");
    citiesList.add("ЃОРЧЕ ПЕТРОВ");

    Log.v("test123", "printing before sorting");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Log.v("test123", citiesList.get(i));
    }

    try {
        macedonian_collator = new RuleBasedCollator(MACEDONIAN_ALPH);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Collections.sort(citiesList, macedonian_collator);

    Log.v("test123", "printing after sorting");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Log.v("test123", citiesList.get(i));
    }
```

and here is the full logcat:

```
    12-31 16:53:52.772 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: printing before sorting
12-31 16:53:52.772 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: ЈАНЕ САНДАНСКИ
12-31 16:53:52.772 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: СКОПЈЕ
12-31 16:53:52.772 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: БЕЛГРАД
12-31 16:53:52.772 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: ЃОРЧЕ ПЕТРОВ
12-31 16:53:52.773 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: expected a reset or setting or comment at index 0 near "!< А < Б < В < Г"
12-31 16:53:52.773 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.makeParseException(CollationRuleParser.java:853)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.setParseError(CollationRuleParser.java:843)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.parse(CollationRuleParser.java:162)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.parse(CollationRuleParser.java:114)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationBuilder.parseAndBuild(CollationBuilder.java:76)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator.internalBuildTailoring(RuleBasedCollator.java:228)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:208)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:294)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici.PocetnaActivity$override.onCreate(PocetnaActivity.java:46)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici.PocetnaActivity$override.access$dispatch(PocetnaActivity.java)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici.PocetnaActivity.onCreate(PocetnaActivity.java:0)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4519)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
12-31 16:53:52.774 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
12-31 16:53:52.775 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: printing after sorting
12-31 16:53:52.775 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: ЃОРЧЕ ПЕТРОВ
12-31 16:53:52.775 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: ЈАНЕ САНДАНСКИ
12-31 16:53:52.775 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: БЕЛГРАД
12-31 16:53:52.775 13271-13271/com.mojavozcka.vozenredmakedonskizeleznici V/test123: СКОПЈЕ
```

P.S. I am working in Android Studio for android app

I tried with a new string using their unicode like `String MACEDONIAN_ALPH_UNICODE = "\u0410 < \u0411 < \u0412 < \u0413 < \u4014 < \u0403 < \u0415 < \u0416 < \u0417 < \u0418 < \u0408 \u041a < \u041b < \u0409 < \u041c < \u041d < \u040a <\u041e < \u041f < \u0420 < \u0421 < \u0422 < \u0420 < \u0423 < \u0424 < \u0425 < \u0426 < \u0427 < \u040f < \u0428";`

Comment: Your code throws a ParseException. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: ah yea, i just added some logging in the catch and it goes there. but I dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: I changed it to `"< А < Б < В < Г < Д < Ѓ < Е < Ж < З < S < И < Ј < К < Л < Љ < М < Н < Њ < О < П < Р < С < Т < Ќ < У < Ф < Х < Ц < Ч < Џ < Ш"` and it seems to sort as intended. I've never used `RuleBasedCollator` before so I don't know if this is the correct fix.

Comment: Java.text.ParseException: expected a reset or setting or comment at index 0 near "!<А < Б < В < Г <"

Comment: @PaulBoddington String like "ЃОРЧЕ ПЕТРОВ" and "ЈАНЕ САНДАНСКИ" are always before the others

Comment: You need to post a minimal example of what you are trying to do. It gives the result I was expecting (http://ideone.com/ReCe6h). If it's not what you were expecting you need to say what you want it to do.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I added the minimal example, sorry for not adding it right when I asked the question

Comment: @UniqueLoLApps and your code still throws an exception. So the collator is null, and you're not sorting with the collator, because it's never constructed correctly.

Comment: @JBNizet I am doing everything as described in the documentation but despite that I am getting java.text.ParseException: expected a reset or setting or comment at index 0 near "!<А <Б <В <Г <Д " when I use Cyrillic letters

Comment: Just as Paul, I've never used RuleBasedCollator, so I can't explain the exception. But he gave you a rule that did parse correctly. Why don't you at least try that?

Comment: ive tried that but I always get ParseException

Comment: did you solve the issue? this collator never worked for me. none of the examples from whole internet doesn't work on android

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is a bug caused by Android's libraries (`android.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator`). When I run the code on a Java development environment, it works. When I run it inside an Android app, it crashes with such a stack trace:

```
2022-08-16 01:33:04.426 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: expected a reset or setting or comment at index 0 near "!< A < Â < B < C"
2022-08-16 01:33:04.426 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.makeParseException(CollationRuleParser.java:855)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.426 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.setParseError(CollationRuleParser.java:845)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.427 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.parse(CollationRuleParser.java:164)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.427 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationRuleParser.parse(CollationRuleParser.java:116)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.427 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at android.icu.impl.coll.CollationBuilder.parseAndBuild(CollationBuilder.java:79)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.427 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.427 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at android.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator.internalBuildTailoring(RuleBasedCollator.java:230)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.427 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at android.icu.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:210)
2022-08-16 01:33:04.427 13286-13444/com.app.debug W/System.err:     at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:290)
```

As a workaround, try to use another method for sorting in Android environment such as [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) with a customized [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).