# How to fix 'expected a reset or setting or comment at index 0 near' in parseException?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I tried sorting a list of hungarian strings, but in Android studio 3.1 I got parseException. In netbeans, the same code works nicely.
The 'megallok' list contains about 300 different strings, e.g.: 
 
0-ás km kő
Piaristák tere
smp, autóbuszforduló
 and so on

Here's my code in netbeans:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
 InterruptedException, ParseException {
    String hunRules = ("< 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 < a,A < á,Á 
                < b,B < c,C < cs,Cs,CS < d,D < dz,Dz,DZ < dzs,Dzs,DZS "
            + " < e,E < é,É < f,F < g,G < gy,Gy,GY < h,H < i,I < í,Í < j,J"
            + " < k,K < l,L < ly,Ly,LY < m,M < n,N < ny,Ny,NY < o,O < ó,Ó "
            + " < ö,Ö < ő,Ő < p,P < q,Q < r,R < s,S < sz,Sz,SZ < t,T "
            + " < ty,Ty,TY < u,U < ú,Ú < ü,Ü < ű,Ű < v,V < w,W < x,X < y,Y 
             < z,Z < zs,Zs,ZS");
    String words[] = {"0-ás km kő","Posta","Széchenyi tér","BARNEVÁL"};
    List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(words);
    Collections.shuffle(strList);
    words = strList.toArray(new String[strList.size()]);
    printStrings(words);
    try {
        RuleBasedCollator spCollator
                = new RuleBasedCollator(hunRules);
        System.out.println();
        sortStrings(spCollator, words);
        printStrings(words);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println("Parse exception for rules");
    }
}
public static void sortStrings(Collator collator, String[] words) {
    String tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            // Compare elements of the words array
            if (collator.compare(words[i], words[j]) > 0) {
                // Swap words[i] and words[j] 
                tmp = words[i];
                words[i] = words[j];
                words[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Android studio version:

```
public class MegallokAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MegallokAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Megallok> mList;
private List<String> mList2;
private HashSet<String> hs;
MegallokAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Megallok> list) {
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;
    hs = new HashSet<>();
    for(Megallok m : mList) {
        hs.add(m.getStop());
    }
    mList.clear();
    mList2 = new ArrayList<>(hs);
    String hunRules = ("< 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 < a,A < á,Á < b,B < c,C < cs,Cs,CS < d,D < dz,Dz,DZ < dzs,Dzs,DZS "
            + " < e,E < é,É < f,F < g,G < gy,Gy,GY < h,H < i,I < í,Í < j,J"
            + " < k,K < l,L < ly,Ly,LY < m,M < n,N < ny,Ny,NY < o,O < ó,Ó "
            + " < ö,Ö < ő,Ő < p,P < q,Q < r,R < s,S < sz,Sz,SZ < t,T "
            + " < ty,Ty,TY < u,U < ú,Ú < ü,Ü < ű,Ű < v,V < w,W < x,X < y,Y < z,Z < zs,Zs,ZS");
    String words[] =mList2.toArray(new String[mList2.size()]);
    try {
        RuleBasedCollator huCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(hunRules);
        sortStrings(huCollator, words);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.d("teszt",pe.getMessage());
    }
    mList2.clear();
    mList2=Arrays.asList(words);
    for(String s : mList2)
    {
        mList.add(new Megallok(s));
    }
    Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<Megallok>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Megallok object1, final Megallok object2) {
            return object1.getStop().compareTo(object2.getStop());
        }
    });
}

public static void sortStrings(Collator collator, String[] words) {
    String tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (collator.compare(words[i], words[j]) > 0) {
                tmp = words[i];
                words[i] = words[j];
                words[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I tried almost everything what I found on the internet, but none of them solved this problem.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73367152/3586084).